Cannot update conda
conda update -n base --all says
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
    current version: 24.5.0
    latest version: 24.7.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda

but conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda gives the exact same message:
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
    current version: 24.5.0
    latest version: 24.7.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda



# All requested packages already installed.

what do I do now?
(reported as a bug)
